# Set Color Intensity of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on the background colour of Views. Each view has different intensity level from 0 to 1. Now I have to set background colour as red based on Views intensity. I have written below code for red colour based on intensity

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: Float(1.0 - cellAlpha), green: 255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1)  //UIColor.red intensity based on views
```

But I am unable to set red colour intensity using above?

Can anyone suggest how to set the intensity of a colour based on the float to vary from 0 to 1.? Please let me know If I have to explain my question.

Comment: What is `cellAlpha`?

Comment: It's 1.0 for each view

Comment: Please respond to my answer and ^ and select if that helps.

Comment: @meaning-matters done. Can you please suggest how to handle for Blue or green color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `cellAlpha` is between 0 and 1:

```
UIColor(colorLiteralRed: CGFloat(255.0 - cellAlpha * 255.0), green: 255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Note that it's `CGFloat`, not `Float`. But better to save you all these `255.0`'s:

```
UIColor(red: CGFloat(1.0 - cellAlpha), green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

However, it sounds as if you want to change the redness only. For this you'd need to use:

```
UIColor(hue: 0.0, saturation: CGFloat(1.0 - cellAlpha), brightness: 1.0 , alpha: 1.0)
```

I just put your `CGFloat(1.0 - cellAlpha)` as saturation; you probably need to adjust/correct that.

Comment: thanks for your edit. Yes, I need only change Red color intensity. Can you please suggest how to handle only for Blue color?

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the other values go up to 255. You need to scale your value up to that as well.

```
let redScale = 255.0 * (1.0 - Float(cellAlpha))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: redScale, green: 255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1)
```